# resource xml/localnotification_provider_paths (aka io.ionic.starter:xml/localnotification_provider_paths) not found

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am facing this error when i have install **ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-local-notification**.i have tried a lot but can't solve still [Here is the image i am facing this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DHAa.png) . 
anyone please help if you know about that.

Answer (score 0):

Capacitor 2.0 uses Android X, that means all plugins have to use Android X too and that one is not updated.

As workarounds you can use Capacitor 1.5.2 or use jetifier to patch plugins to use Android X.

1. npm install jetifier
2. npx jetifier
3. npx cap sync android

During this, if you face an issue while sync android then :

1. Close my code editors (was causing issues for step 2).
2. Running npm install.
3. Running npx cap sync again.